# Body border surrounding all my page (NOT FIXED)

Tags: html, css

What I want is creating a border surrounding all my page content, the top border is fine but the others and especially the bottom border is not positioned where I want, I want it to be always in the bottom of my page.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 45px;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#barTop,
#barLeft,
#barBottom,
#barRight {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f8ee53;
  z-index: 2;
}

#barTop,
#barBottom {
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 25px;
}

#barTop {
  top: 20px;
}

#barBottom {
  bottom: 20px;
}

#barLeft,
#barRight {
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 25px;
}

#barLeft {
  left: 20px;
}

#barRight {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="barTop"></div>
<div id="barRight"></div>
<div id="barBottom"></div>
<div id="barLeft"></div>
```

**Result:**
My border does not include all the content of my page.
[image]

Comment: When you position an element absolutely it's removed from the flow of the document. Why don't you just wrap your content in a div, and give it the border you need?

Comment: @j08691 But when I put an image under my border (in the left corner for example), I can't do it with the z-index!

Answer (score 0):

remove this :

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

and use this

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 45px;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

#barTop, #barLeft, #barBottom, #barRight {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f8ee53;
    z-index: 2;
}
#barTop, #barBottom {
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 25px;
}
#barTop {
top: 20px;
}
#barBottom {
    bottom: 20px;
}
#barLeft, #barRight {
    top: 20px;
    bottom:20px;
    width: 25px;
}
#barLeft {
    left: 20px;
}

#barRight {
    right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do any changes, what I want is surrounding all the content of my page with that border, I want the bottom border to be always in the bottom of my page.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fix this by adding the following under your existing body selector:

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I made a jsfiddle that demonstrates it, with a black background on the body to better illustrate it:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/3u2vcxft/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the padding on the body.  It is not taken into account when the height is calculated at 100%.  Either remove the padding or do what mtr web suggested and add `box-sizing: border-box;`  Run the snippet below to see it work.

```css
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 45px;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#barTop,
#barLeft,
#barBottom,
#barRight {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f8ee53;
  z-index: 2;
}

#barTop,
#barBottom {
  right: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  height: 25px;
}

#barTop {
  top: 20px;
}

#barBottom {
  bottom: 20px;
}

#barLeft,
#barRight {
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 25px;
}

#barLeft {
  left: 20px;
}

#barRight {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="barTop"></div>
<div id="barRight"></div>
<div id="barBottom"></div>
<div id="barLeft"></div>
```

Comment: But when I add the text on your updated code, I get the same problem. The border does not include all my content.